# Save Rich Edit Text to database

Tags: android, database, richtext

I have a edit text box (noteContent). The user has many formats they can use, here are a few:

```
                    if (text.equals("Bold")) {

                        //Make Spannable Text Bold//
                        spannable.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), startSelection, endSelection, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                    }



                    if (text.equals("Italic")) {

                        //Make Spannable Text Italic//
                        spannable.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.ITALIC), startSelection, endSelection, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);



                    if (text.equals("Underline")) {

                        //Make Spannable Text Italic//
                        spannable.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), startSelection, endSelection, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                    }
```

when I save noteContent.getText.toString() To my database, then populate my listview all the rich text is gone.

**How do I save the rich text in my editText to my database. So when I populate the database in my listView using a simpleCursorAdapter the rich Text is there.**

Thanks.

Comment: Why not use HTML in your text?  Instead of spannable string.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to convert the `Spanned` that `getText()` on `EditText` returns into something that you can save in a database, such as an HTML representation. Then, you can convert it back into a `Spanned` to show in a `TextView` at a later point.

One option is to use `Html.toHtml()` and `Html.fromHtml()` from the Android SDK. Another option is to use `SpannedXhtmlGenerator` and `SpannableStringGenerator` from [my CWAC-RichEdit library](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-richedit). Or, you are welcome to come up with your own conversion system, using those implementations as a source of ideas.

Comment: how would it convert in a simple cursor adapter. because that is what I am using after the text value is being retrieved from a datababase

Comment: @Jordan: Attach a `ViewBinder` to the `SimpleCursorAdapter`, and use `Html.fromHtml()` or `SpannableStringGenerator` in the `ViewBinder`.

Comment: how do I use Spannedxhtmlgenerator

Comment: @Jordan: Quoting [the documentation](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-richedit#basic-parsing-and-generating), "Given a `Spanned` (e.g., `getText()` on a `RichEditText`), to get an XHTML representation of the `Spanned`, create an instance of `SpannedXhtmlGenerator` and call `toXhtml()` on it. This will return a `String` of XHTML". So, `new SpannexHtmlGenerator().toXhtml(yourSpannedObject)`.

Comment: Text color works but highlight color and font size dont any ideas @CommonsWare